# How to have "tab selector" effect for "input" elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: ss]
I'm trying to implement those "tab-highlights" that you can see above the form in the screenshot, to my "input" elements, so the user knows which field they've clicked and currently on.

Tried "focus" and "::selection" to change the input field's left side border to turn blue when focused or selected. Didn't work. I have run out of ideas at that point.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRybBr

```
.section1 .uk-input:focus{
    background:#EAEEF2;
    border: 1px, solid, black !important;
}
```

Here's basically what I have on the screenshot (sorry for the php stuff).

I can change the background of the input when focused on. Can't change the border though. It stays blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to change the background color of the selected input (that's what i understand you want to do), you just need to remove the "," from the CSS

Write

```
border: 1px solid black !important;
```

Instead of

```
border: 1px, solid, black !important;
```

Comment: aaaand that's about how my questions go.

Comment: @nimbleclouds they wouldn’t have to, if you used a _validator_ to check your code for errors before you ask … https://validator.w3.org/nu/ (HTML), https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ (CSS)